# Widget Area: Modify $param['xy'] from widget-$n

Tags: widgets, filters

I have different widget areas. One is a horizontal area that may contain eg. 4 widgets next to each other. My Question is how would i add a different eg. `$param['widget_title']` to widget number `$n` (via a filter)?

I already tried using `wp_registered_widgets();` function and te different globals, but with no result.

Comment: The [`dynamic_sidebar_params`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.1/wp-includes/widgets.php#L884) filter is called before each widget is displayed, I think you can use that to achieve what you want. It filters the `$args` and `$instance` parameters that will be passed to the widget.

Comment: @Jan Fabry - i already tried using the `dynamic_sidebar_params` filter with no result. Could you share an example? Thanks!

Comment: @kaiser: Only if you show me your failed attempt first :-) A little code snippet would also explain what you are trying to do better.

Comment: @Jan Fabry - see updated Q. :)

Comment: @Jan Fabry - see another Update :)

Comment: @kaiser: Why do you do the loop on `$wp_registered_widgets`? It seems `dynamic_sidebar_params` is called for each widget, not just for each sidebar, so it should get called 9 times if you have 9 active widgets on that page. But I don't get why you need `$wp_registered_widgets`, you don't seem to read the `$widget` variable in the loop?

Comment: @Jan Fabry - you're right. It does work without it. I thought i'd have to target them over the global array. Didn't get deep enough into the core code. Thanks. Would you copy/paste the Edit, so i can mark it as solution?

Comment: @kaiser: I wrote a more generic solution with a slightly different approach. Feel free to add your own solution as an answer too. Maybe you should then also rollback your question to a version that does not contain the final answer yet?

Comment: @Jan Fabry - done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `dynamic_sidebar_params` filter](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.1/wp-includes/widgets.php#L884) is called before each widget is displayed, so multiple times in the same sidebar. It filters the `$args` and `$instance` parameters that will be passed to the widget.

If you only want to execute it for the third widget of a specific sidebar, you should check for the sidebar ID (found in the `id` value of the `$args` array, which is passed first), and then count the widgets until you arrive at *n*. There are different ways to do this: you can get all widgets of the current sidebar and compare the ID of the *n*-th with the one you are filtering now, or you can just count it in your filter, resetting the count when you get a new sidebar name. Or you could replace `dynamic_sidebar()` in your template with a call to a function of your own that will first reset the widget count and then start filtering.

This is an example of the second type: counting widgets in the function, resetting the count each time we start a new sidebar:

```
add_filter( 'dynamic_sidebar_params', 'wpse15024_dynamic_sidebar_params' );
function wpse15024_dynamic_sidebar_params( $params )
{
    // These are the targets. Modify them here:
    $targeted_sidebar = 'sidebar-bottom';
    $targeted_widget = (int) 3;

    static $widget_counter = array();
    static $current_sidebar = null;

    $args = $params[0];
    $instance = $params[1];

    if ( $current_sidebar != $args['id'] ) {
        $current_sidebar = $args['id'];
        $widget_counter[$current_sidebar] = 0;
    }

    if ( $current_sidebar == $targeted_sidebar && $widget_counter[$current_sidebar] == $targeted_widget ) {
        $args['before_widget'] = '<div id="'.@$args['widget_id'].'" class="span-6 last">';
    }

    $widget_counter[$current_sidebar]++;

    return array( $args, $instance );
}
```

Comment: @Jan Fabry - i edited your answer slightly. I hope you don't mind (if so: sorry).

Comment: @kaiser: Ah, the first time I saw a peer edit and could vote on it! Accepted!

Comment: @Jan Fabry - :)

Comment: @Jan Fabry - another edit (but i'll stop now) :)

Comment: @kaiser: If you make the `before_widget` part configurable you would also need to make the right hand side (the `<div>`) configurable. If we continue on that road we might hide the part of the function that really matters (to me): counting the sidebar widgets and doing something when we reach our widget. I think this example is clear enough now for anyone who wants to adopt it in their code.

Comment: @Jan Fabry - aggree

Answer (score 1):

This way everything works... but take a look at Jans approach.

That's the working code:

```
function wpse15024_modify_widget_params( $params )
{
    // These are the targets. Modify them here:
    $targeted_sidebar = 'sidebar-bottom';
    $targeted_widget = (int) 3;

    $sidebars_widgets = wp_get_sidebars_widgets();

    if ( $params[0]['id'] == $targeted_sidebar && $params[0]['widget_id'] == $sidebars_widgets[$targeted_sidebar][$targeted_widget] )
    {
        $params[0]['before_widget'] = '<div id="'.@$params[0]['widget_id'].'" class="span-6 last">';
    }

    return $params;
}
add_filter( 'dynamic_sidebar_params', 'wpse15024_modify_widget_params' );
```